# Android Studio Create Database error (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "and": syntax error (code 1): ) Detailed Analysis

Tags: java, database, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm trying to use the database and it complains about my "CREATE TABLE".
I looked at different posts and "updated mine on here for the changes I made to CREATE TABLE).
It looks correct compared to other posts and forums, so I am not quite sure why it keeps failing.
It only seems to crash when I try calling the "fill game database" method in the main Activity.
When the object is just created, there is no problem.
I read something about "When the database is created once it is then cached" and so it does not need to happen again.
So I think I'll have to make the database over again, because (maybe) the database is already cached?
However, when the object is created, the CREATE TABLE statement is executed automatically, so I'm not sure why it is screwing up when I call the method to fill the database.

Main Activity Class

```
package tekvision.codedecrypter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import gameInfo.GameDatabase;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//Runs before the application is created
public Button mCampaignButton;


//When the application is created
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //
    // I wanted to call it heat and use it in a toast to make sure its   working
    //Gamedatabase. does not work to find my method

   //


   //Keeps screen on so it doesn't fall asleep
   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

  //Finding button by button id after application is created
  mCampaignButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.campaignButtonID);

   //Checks if the campaign button is clicked
   mCampaignButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        //Toast pop up message
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "campaign select",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.show();


        //Intent to go from main activity to campaign Level Select Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CampaignSelectLevel.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
});

}}
```

Game Database Class

```
package gameInfo;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
* Created by User on 06/06/2015.
*/

//Extends the sql database open helper it will be error until the 2 methods     are added plus the constructor
//the database is saved to a text file
public class GameDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Version number of the database
//Every update to the database will result in going up in the database version number
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Private set of final strings, for the column names in the database
private static final String DATABASE_NAME =
    "Database",
    TABLE_1 = "Answers and Hints",
    TABLE_2 = "classical",
    TABLE_3 = "ancient",
    KEY_ID = "id",
    KEY_HINT = "hint",
    KEY_ANSWER = "answer",
    KEY_QUESTION = "question",
    KEY_INFO = "info",
    KEY_IMAGE = "image";




  //Database Constructor, sets the databases named and the version of the database
  public GameDatabase(Context context){

super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


  //Whenever database is created
 //Creating a table with each column and specify each columns type such as text or integer that is the primary key
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_1 + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT" + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT" + KEY_IMAGE + "IMAGEVIEW" + KEY_HINT + " TEXT" + KEY_INFO + " TEXT)");

}

//When the database is upgraded
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MODERN);

onCreate(db);
}




 //Currently should have ONE row for level on in modern
 public void fillGameDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //Fills information for the first row by a few columns

    //Modern ERA
    values.put(KEY_QUESTION, "US President");
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, "Barack Obama");
    values.put(KEY_HINT, "He is the first African American president");
    values.put(KEY_INFO, "Barack Obama is the 44th President of the United States, and the first African American to hold the office. Born in Honolulu, Hawaii, Obama is a graduate of Columbia University and Harvard Law School, where he served as president of the Harvard Law Review. He was a community organizer in Chicago before earning his law degree. He worked as a civil rights attorney and taught constitutional law at University of Chicago Law School from 1992 to 2004. He served three terms representing the 13th District in the Illinois Senate from 1997 to 2004, running unsuccessfully for the United States House of Representatives in 2000.");
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, "R.drawable.obama.jpg");
    db.insert(TABLE_MODERN, null, values); //inserted a new row into the    database

    db.close();

 }


 //Gets the answers based on the era nd level provided,
 //db is database extension dont need to pass it
 public Cursor getAnswer(String table, int level){
 SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

 Cursor cursor;

//All one row of data
String[] projections = {KEY_QUESTION, KEY_ANSWER, KEY_HINT, KEY_INFO, KEY_IMAGE};

//Calling query method
//Pass table name, the projections(names of columns), selection (data argument), selection arguments, group rows
//filter by row groups, sort order, you can pass null for ones you dont want to enter
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_ANSWER + " FROM " + TABLE_MODERN + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "=" + level, null);

db.close();
return cursor;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name contains spaces... so you should enclose it in square brackets, like this `[Answers and Hints]`.
Or, better, use underscores, like this `Answers_and_Hints`

Otherwise, the SQLite  DDL (Data Definition Language) would interpret the different words as different commands.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that spaces would make a difference in table names in a database. It kinda works, My raw query in getAnswer brings a weird code instead of the string text. such as 3313b4

Comment: I have to wait the time limit before I could accept